# Is it safe to delete the root checkpoint in hyper-v?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v

I'm running out of space on my machine, due to multiple VMs. I figured I could free some space by deleting the root (and only) checkpoint of each VM. Is this safe? I figure that since it's a checkpoint, it should be safe to delete, but the warning says I'm "Deleting the VM" which is worrisome.
[image: Root checkpoint highligted]

Comment: to get rid of automatic checkpoints you may shut down the VM -> the automatic checkpoint will get merged -> you can then disable automatic checkpoints in the VM settings.

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz Thanks, I'll do that!